# How to mock window/document with mocha/chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

When I try to unit test the `getElement` function

```
class BarFoo {
    getElement() {
        return document.querySelector('#barfoo');
    }
}
```

mocha doesn't know anything about `document`, so I figured that you might do something like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    global.document = {
        querySelector: () => { ... }
    }
}
```

Although this works, I'm wondering if this is the correct approach and maybe there is a package available to solve this issue, because my approach can get laborious if more browser API's are used ?

Answer (score 27):

There are a few options available to you:

## Option 1: Use [JSDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom)

By adding a DOM to your code, you can unit test much of your client-side code within node.js

## Option 2: Use MOCHA on the client

Mocha does run inside the client and you can use separate client-side unit tests.  This tends to be my preferred approach as I can test against specific browsers and not a specific JS implantation.

## <strike>Option 3: Use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)</strike>

<strike>PhantomJS allows you to control a headless browser within your testing environment.</strike>

## Option 4: [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/headless-karma-mocha-chai)

Now that Headless Chrome is out, the  PhantomJS maintainer has retired.

Comment: I guess that the JSDOM version is the fastest. It looks like what I need!

Comment: Why did you cross-out PhantomJS? Doesn't 2.0 solve issues?

Comment: @LeeGee "Important: PhantomJS development is suspended until further notice (more details)." -- I can't recommend a package that is no longer maintained when there are other options available.

Comment: could you provide more details for the option 2 ? @JeremyJStarcher

Comment: Headless Chrome is also outdated. Nowadays use Puppeteer/Playwright.

Answer (score 18):

I have been writing tests similar to what you proposed when I just needed to mock a certain function on window:

```
it('html test', function () {
    const windowRef = global.window;
    global.window = {document: {querySelector: () => null}};
    const lib = require('lib-that-uses-queryselector');
    assert(true);
    global.window = windowRef;
});
```

I have been using [mock-browser](https://github.com/darrylwest/mock-browser) in other tests when I wanted a more complete window object:

```
it('html test', function () {
     const windowRef = global.window;
     const MockBrowser = require('mock-browser').mocks.MockBrowser;
     global.window = new MockBrowser().getWindow();
     const lib = require('lib-that-uses-window');
     assert(true);
     global.window = windowRef;
});
```

Note that you probably want to restore the window object (`global.window = windowRef;` above) after [messing with globals](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Mess-with-globals).

Comment: global.window worked for me, highly recommend it as you don't need any extra libs.

Comment: I used the idea here but I prefer 
const window = global.window;
global.window = {...};
...
global.window = window;

In case a dumby window object ever gets added at a global scale.

Comment: True! Edited to reflect that now.

Comment: @SimonBengtsson, `global.window = window` will not restore the widow object since the window const created with `window = global.window` is a copy by reference. 

Instead you can clone the window at the top of the test with: `preservedWindow = Object.assign({}, window)` then reassign when done testing: `global.window = preservedWindow` (note that could still be problematic since Object.assign only does a shallow copy, but should be good enough in most cases)

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't it be better to use the original window object instead of a copy?